# MM/DD comparison issue in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using below SQL query to get data by mentioning date range without year.

`Select * from table where Left(Convert(Varchar(10),Cast(createddate As Date),101),5) between '11/01' and '12/31'`

The above query works say when the user enter the date range as '11/01' to '12/31'. But, when the user enters anything like '11/01' to '01/31' or '05/31' to 02/28' etc, the query is not returning any data.

Is it possible to make it work for above ranges?

Comment: what do you expect? You're not comparing dates. You're comparing **STRINGS**. string comparison rules are FAR simpler than date comparison rules. If you want to compare dates, then convert your user input into proper dates and leave you db fields AS dates.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `month()` function:

```
Select *
from table
where month(nm_birthdate) in (11, 12);
```

Your query, however, should work because 101 zero-pads days and months.

If you want to find birthdays between two dates in MM/DD format, you could do:

```
where (@startmmdd < @endmmdd) and convert(varchar(5), nm_birthdate, 101) between @startmmdd and @endmmdd) or
      (@startmmdd > @endmmdd) and convert(varchar(5), nm_birthdate, 101) not between @endmmdd and @startmmdd)
```

There might be a little adjustment depending on whether or not you want to include the end points.

Notes:

- The variables `@startmmdd` and `@endmmdd` need to be in MM/DD format.  Leading zeros are needed for months and days less than 10.
- Convert conveniently uses the length of the data type, so `left()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEPART, something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE datepart(month, birthdate) IN (11, 12)
```

Of course, you can combine it with:

```
    datepart(day, birthdate)
```

in order to get more complex condition.
Hope it helps